# Is it a bad practice to not check if fetch request failed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my app ( i'm using next.js but it's more a general question ) i have a button that updates number of likes when clicked (+1). Here is relevant part of code:

```
  const handleLikeClick = () => {

    setNumberLikes(numberLikes + 1)
    fetch('/api/updateLikes?origin=so-filter', {
      method: 'POST'
    })

  }
```

And my API:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from '../../utils/mongodb'

export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase()
    const { origin } = req.query

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      await db.collection('likes').findOneAndUpdate({ page: origin }, { $inc: { likes: 1 }})
      res.status(200)
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.status(500)
  }
}
```

I don't really care much if this **POST** request fails or not, therefore, i'm not checking for it and there is no additional logic if it actually fails. Is it a bad practice to do so ? Should i actually `res.status(200).json({success:'updated'})` and `.then` my `fetch` request? Thank you.

Comment: If you really don't care, you can ignore errors (whether network-level, http-level or application level), but currently your code will cause unhandled promise rejection warnings. You should always have a `catch` at the end of your promise chains, even if it's a `.catch(e => { /* do nothing! */ })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want to achieve at the user level.

Although the result doesn't influence the flow of your program and doesn't break it, most of the times there is some importance to let the fetcher/user know what happened with the request.

Sometimes (like in your case) it can have an impact to the user experience. In your example, in case of failure, I think the user should get an error message or some sort of visualization that the like didn't cast, so he could try again or at least know that there was a problem.

(I'm pretty sure Facebook, Youtube, and StackOverflow just grays out upvoted or likes if something went wrong. In StackOverflow you even get a message with the specific error).

**Edit**

Code-wise it will work just fine since you are care to give a returned status code in any case (of success or failure).

From the [documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.`

(Notice that you will want to handle network failures though).

Comment: I see your point, thanks. But from a coding prospective, is the code above ok if i don't care about letting a user know that his 'like' failed ?

Comment: Yes it is since you are care to give a returned status code in any case (of success or failure). From the documents: `The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.` [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).